# Does jobs list only background and stopped jobs?

Tags: bash, job-control

When `jobs` is run in a shell, does it mean that all other jobs must be either background or stopped? Is there no foreground jobs?

Does `jobs` list only background and stopped jobs?

Comment: How do you run `jobs` if there is a foreground job running? `jobs` only shows the jobs that are attached to a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

**jobs** command is used to list the jobs that you are running in the background and in the foreground. If the prompt is returned with no information no jobs are present. Reference link [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-jobs-command-examples-usage-syntax/).